# How many ways we can transfer value from servlet to jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to transfer servlet parametre to jsp file?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way that i know.

1. Setting value in Request Attribute.

   - in servlet you can use following code.

request.setAttribute("name", "value");

and you need forward request to jsp page not to redirect. for this you can use RequestDispatcher Class. please refer following link
http://www.roseindia.net/help/java/d/requestdispatcher.shtml

1. Setting Value in Session Attribute.

   - in session you need to get session then put value in it.
     session.setAttribute("name", "value");

best way is to set value in request Attribute. and if you need value till session expires at that time you can use session.

Comment: I think you are new to Stackoverflow. if you are agree with answer then just click on right sign to left side of my answer.